# Why is Spyder so slow in OS X? Is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda

I have Spyder installed as part of the Anaconda Python analytics package and I'm finding the editor to be very slow.  There's always a half-second lag time between key presses and the letter showing up on screen.  I'm using Spyder on a fairly new i7 MacBook.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Are you using Mavericks or Mountain Lion?

Comment: I am using Mavericks.  It was also slow with Mountain Lion.

Comment: We haven't heard of a problem like in Mountain Lion but there is definitely one in Mavericks. I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is generated by Qt, the graphical library Spyder is built upon. Not only Spyder but all applications that use Qt have shown this problem.

A detailed explanation of the problem can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1623) where we are also trying to find a a solution.

Comment: Carlos gives a solution here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2724. I did so and it resolved it for me.

Comment: We are now in 2021 and its still very slow. Are you guys any closer to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As Carlos mentioned, the problem is currently with Qt. Over the past couple months, people have found a workaround ([answer #29](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1623)) as the folks at [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) have a working distribution. People have found success installing qt on Mavericks with `brew install pyqt` and then installing spyder through pip with `pip install spyder`. That said, it seems that anaconda uses it's own version of Qt, so I haven't figured out yet how to get it working for the anaconda distribution. It seems either some sort of linking could work, or someone could create a conda package with a working pyqt in it.

Comment: The problem with Anaconda is that ships with Qt 4.7 in Mac, which surely will have more issues with Mavericks than 4.8 (PS. I don't know if Anaconda 1.9 would have changed that).

Answer (score 2):

Spyder 3 beta 3 resolves the lag while typing in the editor under OSX.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

conda update qt pyqt

conda install -c spyder-ide spyder==3.0.0b3

Comment: Fixed my problem on OSX. You rock.