# Spyder freeze on Debian system

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm working on a Debian Linux distribution using Anaconda/Spyder.  I am currently running very simple code, and at some point Spyder freezes for 30 seconds to a minute before I can click, type, anything.  I'm wondering if this is an issue with the Qt graphical library Spyder ([Why is Spyder so slow in OS X? Is there a way to make it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987543/why-is-spyder-so-slow-in-os-x-is-there-a-way-to-make-it-faster)).  Does anyone have any suggestions?  At present, the freezes are so often that I'm unable to get anything done.

Thanks.

Comment: What Anaconda packages are you using? Also, does it only occur whilst using these packages?

Comment: numpy, pylab, gdal - Yes, it appears to only occur when using these packages.

Comment: Then it is probably not the same problem I had whilst using the Anaconda Accelerate package (GPU library for CUDA), which required me to use the proprietary NVIDIA driver for my graphics card. The proprietary driver was quite buggy, causing my system to freeze sporadically. As it doesn't happen  to you otherwise, it's probably unrelated. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.